# numpy array of lists to 1d array? (flatten array of list objects)

Tags: python, numpy

I have to flatten array of lists to 1d numpy array. I use this:

```
import numpy as np

orig = np.array([[1,2], [3]], dtype=object)

lst = []
for x in orig:
    lst.extend(x)

result = np.array(lst)  # makes array([1, 2, 3])
```

Is there a standard numpy function or method to do this (similar to `np.flatten`)?

Comment: `np.hstack(orig.ravel())`

Comment: @Ali_Sh oh indeed, just `np.hstack(orig)`! Turns out hstack allows arbitrary size internal arrays for 1d dimensional data

Comment: `hstack` treats the argument as a list of arrays - split on the first dimension.